# addEventListener and removeEventListener using forEach

Tags: javascript

Why does "div[1]" works, and why "div.nextElementSibling" doesn't, since in console.log they appears identically when forEach method deals with first div

```
<--HTML-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <script defer src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='div'>first</div>
    <div class='div'>second</div>
</body>
</html>

<--JS-->

const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.div')

divs.forEach((div, id) => {

    const clg = () => { 

        console.log(id)

        //it works
        divs[1].removeEventListener('click', clg)

        //it doesn't
        div.nextElementSibling.removeEventListener('click', clg)

    }

    div.addEventListener('click', clg)

    //this DOM's elements for div1 are the same
    console.log(divs[1],div.nextElementSibling)
})
```

Comment: It probably works for the first iteration of the `forEach` loop. But the `forEach` will iterate twice in your example, once for each div. In the second loop, `div` is "second." And in that loop, `div.nextElementSibling` will be null, because there isn't another element after the second div.

Answer (score 2):

This is because, divs[1] will always show fix value no matter what which cycle is running inside a forEach loop.

As div contains 2 element

```
<div class='div'>first</div>
<div class='div'>second</div>
```

Therefore div value is going to change for each cycle of the forEach loop and divs[1] is a fix value that is

```
<div class='div'>second</div>
```

Now the console logs

```
// Cycle 0
// Console.log(divs[1])
<div class='div'>second</div>
// Console.log(div.nextElementSibling)
<div class='div'>second</div>

// Cycle 1
// Console.log(divs[1])
<div class='div'>second</div>
// Console.log(div.nextElementSibling)
null
```